# how to pass a constant in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsvalue

I'm wondering if there is a way to pass a constant like UITableViewStylePlain into NSDictionary.

I am passing value types using NSValue like so:

```
CGRect myRec = CGRectMake(0,0,320,568);
NSDictionary *myDic = @{@"val":[NSValue valueWithCGRect:myRec]};
CGRect yourRec = [[myDic valueForKey:@"val"] CGRectValue];
```

My question is how do I do this for a constant like UITableViewStylePlain?  Something like this:

```
NSDictionary *myDic = @{@"style":[NSValue value:UITableViewStylePlain withObjCType:enum]};
```

I realize enum is not an ObjectiveC type... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `enum` usually holds `NSInteger` (sometimes `NSUInteger`), so an `NSNumber` also can be good enough in that case, like:

```
NSDictionary * myDic = @{ @"style" : @(UITableViewStylePlain) };
```

Answer (score 2):

Enum values are numbers so you can use `NSNumber` to store them in the dictionary :

```
NSDictionary *myDic = @{@"style":@[NSNumber numberWithInt:UITableViewStylePlain]};
```